# infinispan 10.1 No marshaller registered for Java type java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, infinispan, hot-rod

While try to store the list object in the infinispan cache is throwing the error. I have referred some forums and included whitelist of list class too, but still getting the same error.

Note: Server hosted remotely

Imports

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.DefaultTemplate;
import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCache;
import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager;
import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.infinispan.commons.api.CacheContainerAdmin;
```

Code:

```
// Setup up a clustered cache manager
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.addServer().host("127.0.0.1").port(11322).addJavaSerialWhiteList("java.util.List","java.util.ArrayList");
    // Connect to the server
    RemoteCacheManager cacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager(builder.build());
    // Create test cache, if such does not exist
    cacheManager.administration().withFlags(CacheContainerAdmin.AdminFlag.VOLATILE).getOrCreateCache("test123", DefaultTemplate.DIST_SYNC);
    // Obtain the remote cache
    RemoteCache<String, List<String>> cache = cacheManager.getCache("test123");
    List<String> test = new ArrayList();
    cache.put("key", test);
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No marshaller registered for Java type java.util.ArrayList
at org.infinispan.protostream.impl.SerializationContextImpl.getMarshallerDelegate(SerializationContextImpl.java:279)
at org.infinispan.protostream.WrappedMessage.writeMessage(WrappedMessage.java:240)
at org.infinispan.protostream.ProtobufUtil.toWrappedByteArray(ProtobufUtil.java:181)
at org.infinispan.protostream.ProtobufUtil.toWrappedByteArray(ProtobufUtil.java:176)
at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.ProtoStreamMarshaller.objectToBuffer(ProtoStreamMarshaller.java:69)
at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.AbstractMarshaller.objectToByteBuffer(AbstractMarshaller.java:70)
at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.marshall.MarshallerUtil.obj2bytes(MarshallerUtil.java:99)
```

Answer (score 2):

Working after added the `.marshaller(new JavaSerializationMarshaller())`. Hope this change is correct if any better option available please post it

```
builder.addServer().host("127.0.0.1").port(ConfigurationProperties.DEFAULT_HOTROD_PORT).marshaller(new JavaSerializationMarshaller()).addJavaSerialWhiteList("java.util.List","java.util.ArrayList");
```

Comment: This allows you to marshall `ArrayList` directly as Java `Serialization` is used. Whilst this is simpler than utilising a wrapper object with the default marshaller, for the majority of cases this will be slower. Please see our documentation for more details https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#marshalling

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the ProtoStream marshaller does not currently support the direct marshalling of `ArrayList`, but this is planned for a subsequent ProtoStream release [IPROTO-118](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/IPROTO-118).

To marshall `ArrayList`, or any `Collection` implementation, with Infinispan's default Protostream marshaller, it's necessary to wrap the collection in a user defined class and add it as a field. For example the following class allows ArrayLists to be stored:

```
public class Book {

   @ProtoField(number = 1, collectionImplementation = ArrayList.class)
   final List<String> authors;

   @ProtoFactory
   Book(List<String> authors) {
      this.authors = authors;
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the feature has been implemented and merged but I'm personally getting the same error with 4.4.1.Final

Comment: @Lori What version of Infinispan are you using?

Comment: Latest version, 13.0.5 and 4.4.1.Final for proto

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?